# Ffmpeg ./configure not found

Tags: ffmpeg, configure, libx264

I'm trying to install ffmpeg with libvpx & libx264 on my vps. Centos07. I've followed these instructions https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos to the T.

Now when I try to run

```
cd ~/ffmpeg; ./configure --enable-libvpx --enable-gpl --enable-libx264
```

it returns

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

When I try ffmpeg -v

```
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libx264.so.148: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and ldd $(which ffmpeg) returns

```
root@host [~/ffmpeg_sources]# ldd $(which ffmpeg)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4fb86000)
libxcb.so.1 => /lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f4972e27000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f4972c23000)
libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007f4972a1a000)
libxcb-shape.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007f4972816000)
libx264.so.148 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4972513000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f49722ee000)
libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007f49720de000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f4971ec7000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4971cab000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f49718e9000)
libXau.so.6 => /lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f49716e4000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4973056000)
```

I've followed all the instructions exactly - is there something I'm missing?

Comment: *Questions here should involve programmatic use of the libraries, API, or tools. **Questions about interactive use of the FFmpeg command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production.*** Your question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: @Laurel IIRC, users with more than 3k reputation can vote to migrate it to Super User (off topic -> belongs on another site -> SU) but it almost never happens due to too few votes.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I left that message "yesterday" when I had no CVs left. Too few votes indeed, but I have some now so I'm able to do things.